# How to automatically move roots with coefficients to the right of the equation?

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

[How can I move one term with Sqrt to the right side of equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283925/how-can-i-move-one-term-with-sqrt-to-the-right-side-of-equation)

The root of the previous problem does not have a coefficient in front of it, so using the previous code for this problem has no effect.

```
5 (-5 + Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 + y)^2]) + 2 y == 0
```

How to identify a radical with coefficients in front of it and move it to the right of the equation

to get the result:

```
-25 + 2 y == -5 Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 + y)^2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put more effort in understanding the answers you've obtained:

```
Expand[5 (-5 + Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 + y)^2]) + 2 y == 0] /. 
 a_ + b_ Sqrt[c_] == 0 :> a == -b Sqrt[c]
(* -25 + 2 y == -5 Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 + y)^2] *)
```

Comment: In[654]:= 
Expand[5 (-5 + Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 + y)^2]) + 2 y == 0] /. 
 a_ + b_.*Sqrt[c_] == 0 :> a == -b Sqrt[c]

Out[654]= -25 + 2 y == -5 Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 + y)^2]

In[655]:= 
Expand[(-5 + Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 + y)^2]) + 2 y == 0] /. 
 a_ + b_.*Sqrt[c_] == 0 :> a == -b Sqrt[c]

Out[655]= -5 + 2 y == -Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 + y)^2]