# How do I extract terms from a complicated polynomial?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials

The polynomial is:

```
b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 + b^2 x2 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 - 
  b^2 x1 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 λ - a^2 x2 y0 λ + 
  a^2 x0 y1 λ - a^2 x2 y1 λ - a^2 x0 y2 λ + 
  a^2 x1 y2 λ == 0
```

I want to:

1. Find terms that contain `x1 y2` and `x2 y1`, and merge them separately into similar terms. The rest of the terms are not required, and the overall form of the result should be `a x1 y2 + b x2 y1 + c`.
2. Find terms that contain `x1 y2 - x2 y1` or `x2 y1 - x1 y2`, and merge them into similar terms separately. The remaining terms are not required, and the results should be `a (x1y2-x2y1)+b` or `a (x2y1-x1y2)+b`.

I've tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
b^2 (x1 y0 - x2 y0 + x0 y1 + x2 y1 - (x0 + x1) y2) + 
   a^2 (-x2 (y0 + y1) + x0 (y1 - y2) + x1 (y0 + y2)) λ == 
  0 // Expand
% // Collect[#, {x1y2, x2y1}] &
```

The end result requirements are in the following form:

```
b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 \[Lambda] - 
  a^2 x2 y0 \[Lambda] + a^2 x0 y1 \[Lambda] - 
  a^2 x0 y2 \[Lambda] + (x2 y1 - x1 y2) (b^2 - a^2 \[Lambda]) == 0
```

Comment: 1. Check `Collect`. 2. What do you mean by "Find items that contain x1y2 x2y1 or x2y1 x1y2"? Terms involving `x1 y2 x2 y1` or `x2 y1 x1 y2`? If so, I don't find such term in the given equation.

Comment: If you've really understood the answers under your previous questions e.g. [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283936/1871), this should not be a problem for you. Once again (I can't remember how many times I've typed this line), please put more effort in understanding the answers you've obtained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

Let us introduce the following function:

```
f[expr_, factor1_, factor2_] := 
 Select[Select[expr, MemberQ[#, factor1] &], MemberQ[#, factor2] &];
```

Here is your expression:

```
eq = b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 + b^2 x2 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 - 
   b^2 x1 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 \[Lambda] - a^2 x2 y0 \[Lambda] + 
   a^2 x0 y1 \[Lambda] - a^2 x2 y1 \[Lambda] - a^2 x0 y2 \[Lambda] + 
   a^2 x1 y2 \[Lambda] == 0;
```

Step 1:

```
expr1 = f[eq[[1]], x1, y2] + f[eq[[1]], y1, x2]

(*  b^2 x2 y1 - b^2 x1 y2 - a^2 x2 y1 \[Lambda] + a^2 x1 y2 \[Lambda]  *)
```

Step 2:

```
Collect[expr1, {x1*y2, x2*y1}]

(*  x2 y1 (b^2 - a^2 \[Lambda]) + x1 y2 (-b^2 + a^2 \[Lambda])  *)
```

Step 3:

```
expr1 // Simplify

(*  (x2 y1 - x1 y2) (b^2 - a^2 \[Lambda])  *)
```

If you need the rest of expression, do the following:

```
eq[[1]] - expr1 // Simplify

(*  (x1 y0 - x2 y0 + x0 (y1 - y2)) (b^2 + a^2 \[Lambda])  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: The result should be displayed completely, which is equal to the original formula.

Comment: @csn It should be displayed completely? Then display it!

Answer (score 5):

```
expr = b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 + b^2 x2 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 - 
   b^2 x1 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 λ - a^2 x2 y0 λ + 
   a^2 x0 y1 λ - a^2 x2 y1 λ - a^2 x0 y2 λ + 
   a^2 x1 y2 λ;

factorsOfInterest = {x1 y2 , x2 y1};
t1 = factorsOfInterest . Coefficient[expr, factorsOfInterest]
t2 = Collect[(expr - t1 ) // Simplify, {x0, y0}]
t1 + t2
```

> x2 y1 (b^2 - a^2 λ) +   x1 y2 (-b^2 + a^2 λ) + (x1 - x2) y0 (b^2 + a^2
> λ) +   x0 (y1 - y2) (b^2 + a^2 λ)

```
(t1 + t2 // Expand) === expr
```

> True